# discord.js how to get the number members in a guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

`discord.js version 12`

How do I check the number of members in a guild?

```
if(message.content === 'numberguild'){
  message.channel.send(`${message.guild.size}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(message.content === 'numberguild'){
  message.channel.send((client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).memberCount))
}

or 

const a = (client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).memberCount)
if(message.content === 'numberguild'){
  message.channel.send(a + " members")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of `message.channel.send()` to `message.guild.memberCount`

Also move 'numberguild' inside a `.includes()` after the `message.content` to avoid executing the command when you don't want to.

Fixed code:

`if(message.content.includes('numberguild')){ message.channel.send(message.guild.memberCount) }`